# It stoppes working after adding the records for the first student and it doesnt saves the data on the file

Tags: c, algorithm, file, struct

//Whenever I try to add student information it lets me enter the details for the first student and then stops working after pressing enter. Please help, I have a presentation in two days

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define NAME 50
#define LNAME 50
#define AGE 2
#define SUBJECT 200
#define ID 50


void Students();
void Subjects();


struct student{
    int ID_no;
    char name[20];
    char lname[20];
    int age[2] ;
    int id_grupi;
}; struct student stu;

struct subject
{
    char subject[20];  
    int mark[2];

};
 struct subject sub;
//initializing the files used in the program

  FILE *fp;
int main()
{
  int choice=0;
 system("cls");
           printf("\n\t\t    ======================================");
            printf("\n\t\t    |            Options:                |");
           printf("\n\t\t    |                                    |");
          printf("\n\t\t   |  [1] Add a student                 |");
           printf("\n\t\t   |  [2] Add subject                   |");
             printf("\n\t\t   ======================================");
            printf("\n");
    scanf(" %i", &choice);
    switch (choice)
    {   
    case 1:
      Students(); 
    break;
    case 2:
      Subjects();

    default: printf("**Invalid Input.**\n");
 }
 return (0);
 }

void Students() //problem when pressing enter after giving the details
{
  int select;
  char choice1;          
                            while (select!=2){
                             system("cls");
   printf("\n\t\t              ======================================");
   printf("\n\t\t    |                MENU:               |");
   printf("\n\t\t    |                                    |");
   printf("\n\t\t    |  [1] Add a student              |");
   printf("\n\t\t    |  [2] Go back to main menu                |");
   printf("\n\t\t    ======================================");
                             printf("\n\t\t\tSelect:\n ");
                                scanf("%d", &select);
                                switch(select)
                                {
    case 1: 
    system("cls");
    printf("\n\t\t\t\t-ADD A STUDENT-\n");
    printf("NAME: ");
    scanf("%s",stu.name);
    printf("LAST NAME: ");
    scanf("%s",stu.lname);
    printf("AGE: ");
    scanf("%d",stu.age);
    printf("ID: ");
    scanf("%d",stu.ID_no); 
     fp=fopen("studentfile.txt","a+");
          fprintf(fp,"\n%s    \n",stu.name);
    fprintf(fp,"\n%s    \n",stu.lname);
    fprintf(fp,"\n%d    \n",stu.age);
    fprintf(fp,"\n%s    \n",stu.ID_no);

     fclose(fp);

                            }
                        }
  select=1;
  main();
}




void Subjects() //runs succesfully
{
  char choice2;
  int select2;
                                                                                               /* Choice2 */

                while(select2!=2){
      printf("\n\t\t    ======================================");
      printf("\n\t\t    |                MENU:               |");
      printf("\n\t\t    |                                    |");
      printf("\n\t\t    |  [1] Add subjects per student       |");
      printf("\n\t\t    |  [2] Main menu                 |");
      printf("\n\t\t    ======================================");
                             printf("\n\t\t\tSelect: ");

                                scanf("%d", &select2);
                                switch (select2)
                                {
                                case 1:
                                        system("cls");
                                        printf("\n\t\t\t\t-Add subjects-");
                                        printf("\n\t\tID : ");
                                        scanf("%d", &stu.ID_no);
                          fp=fopen("studentfile.txt","a+");  
                         fprintf(fp,"\n ID no:    %d\n",stu.ID_no); 
                                         int i=0,l;
                                         printf("Add number of subjects: ");
                                         scanf("%d",&l);
                                         for(i=0;i<l; i++)
                                         {
                                                printf("Subject %d: ",i+1);
                                              scanf("%s",sub.subject);
                                              scanf("%s",sub.mark);


                             fprintf(fp,"Subject:   %s\n",sub.subject);
                     fprintf(fp,"Mark**strong text**:    %s\n",sub.nota);
                                            }



                                        fclose(fp);

                            }
                        }
  select2=1;
  main();**strong text** //runs the main function again
}`
```

Comment: Very bad code.... Lots of problems. To fix your problem use `&` before the variable name when scanning a `%d` and change `int age[2] ;` to `int age;`

Comment: I've tried that but still doesn't work

Comment: Your code is so unreadable and has a lot of problems that (almost) nobody will help you.  Please format and indent your code properly.

Comment: where is the problem? This is not the entire code, just the readng part. It's Ok when I run it except the part which writes data from structure student. There's my problem. The other structure excecutes fine.

Comment: Just wading through your code, for starters, in `Subjects()` you declare an uninitialised variable called `select` then you proceed to test it's value on the next line.  Probably not the problem you are looking for, but just saying.....

Comment: @SaraVrusho , One of the main problems is that you are not initializing variables like `select`. Initialize them so that your code doesn't exhibit Undefined Behavior. This can be seen in all questions that you've posted till date. BTW, If you have a problem, we are happy to help you on some conditions. 1) You need to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and 2)you need to give details about what is not working as expected. Also, 3) format and indent code so that it is easily readable.

Comment: OK look, you are failing to initialise your `select` variables in all the other functions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use sscanf and fgets, instead of scanf. Like this:

fgets(input, 50, stdin);

sscanf(input, "%d", &choice);

Declaring input as:

char input[50];

You should use it every time you want to read something from the stdin, or a file, it leads to a "strong program".

Answer (score 0):

Aside from all the issues of uninitialised variables mentioned in comments, you have a problem with your `fopen` in the `Modify` function.  To quote the doc:

```
"w+"  Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does not
      exist, otherwise it is truncated.  The stream is positioned at
      the beginning of the file.
```

So, every time you open the file in `Modify` with `wb+` it gets truncated to zero bytes.  In addition, the way you test the `fopen` is not too good, and your error messages not not too good either.  Try this as a general theme:

```
          fp = fopen("studentfile.dat", "r+b");

          if (fp == NULL)
              perror("Unable to open studentfile.dat for read and write")
```

There may be other errors.....